# where can I find the whole list of props like toValue and duration to use

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning **Animation** for **React Native**. I have some questions/issues about how to use the facebook documentation. For instance, they have this part of code:

```
Animated.timing(                            // Animate value over time
  this.state.fadeAnim,                      // The value to drive
  {
     toValue: 1,                   // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
    duration: 10000,                             // Animate to final value of 1
  }
).start();
```

but then where can I find the whole list of props like `toValue` and `duration` to use? i am sure that there are more of them but there should be something like a list of them somewhere in the doc and we don't have to just pick them from the code examples that they have. I have this general issue with other parts of the doc. so i see something in the code example but don't know how to get them all.

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided is using the `timing` method that can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#timing

As you can see, the first argument should be the value you want to change and the second is an object containing the different options you want to use. `toValue` is just the value you want it to be changed to and the other options like `duration` are listed there in the link. Hope this helps.

Comment: so in that link that you gave me, what don't we have toValue in config part?

Comment: You do, that's why you see it with duration in your example.

Answer (score 0):

For everything you might not find in the Official Docs, just take a look at the source code :)

For example for Animated.Timing:
[Here's the link to the source file in Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Animated/src/animations/TimingAnimation.js)

where you can see:

```
export type TimingAnimationConfig = AnimationConfig & {
  toValue: number | AnimatedValue | {x: number, y: number} | AnimatedValueXY,
  easing?: (value: number) => number,
  duration?: number,
  delay?: number,
};
```

so **toValue**, **easing**, **duration** & **delay** are the properties you can pass.

Remember, Code never lies, but Docs sometimes do (or just not show it all) :)